# Posting a message "https://chat.stackoverflow.com" in chat shows a picture for Stack Overflow that links to the stackoverflow.com homepage

Tags: bug, chat

Look here:

[image: A message with a oneboxed picture for Stack Overflow]

I posted this message in Chat:

> https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

It oneboxed like if I had posted

> https://stackoverflow.com/

This doesn't happen with a link to `https://ja.stackoverflow.com`:

[image: Japanese Stack Overflow oneboxes right]

so this can have exceptions. Testing in the sandbox, `https://aaaa.stackoverflow.com` does not onebox as anything.

Testing with `https://chat.scifi.stackexchange.com/`, **`chat.{valid site.stackexchange/stackoverflow}.com` oneboxes as that site's homepage, making posting a plain link to Meta's Chat, main Chat, or Stack Overflow's Chat impossible in Chat**.

**Can this be fixed, please?**

Comment: Sorry this doesn't make any sense, I'll fix it tomorrow :o